# AWS IoT Device SDK for Embedded Cでのcmake Error : LIB_RTについて

Tags: macos, aws, cmake

AWS IoT Device SDK for Embedded Cをチュートリアルに沿って「$cmake ..」を実行したところ下記のエラーが発生しました。
LIB_RTを解決するために何をしたら良いでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。
環境はintel macとなっています。

チュートリアル:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-embedded-c-sdk.html

```
$ cmake ..
~
中略
~

-- Configuring done
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
LIB_RT
    linked by target "ota_demo_core_http" in directory ~/Core2-for-AWS-IoT-EduKit/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/demos/ota/ota_demo_core_http
    linked by target "ota_demo_core_mqtt" in directory ~/Core2-for-AWS-IoT-EduKit/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/demos/ota/ota_demo_core_mqtt

-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

Comment: `LIB_RT` というのはおそらく Linux distribution などで提供されている RealTime library(`librt.so`) の事かと思います。少し調べてみると、どうやら Mac OSX では提供されていない模様ですが、エラーメッセージを見るとdemos ディレクトリにあるプログラムなのでビルドの必要はなさそうです。そこで、[aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/blob/main/CMakeLists.txt#L34) で `BUILD_DEMOS` が `ON` にセットされているのを `OFF` に変更すれば、この問題を回避できるかもしれません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
やはり試してみましたが、結果は同じでした。
よく考えてみればEmbedded CなのにMacOSでコンパイルすること自体が間違いなのかもしれません。
ちなみに後学のためにお伺いしたいのですが、どのような検索ワードで検索されましたでしょうか。私の方ではまともに結果が出なかったもので、ちゃんと自分で調べられるようになるため教えていただければと思います。。。参考サイト等教えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: はい、`cmake LIB_RT osx` で検索しました(https://www.google.com/search?q=cmake+LIB_RT+osx&complete=0)。後は user45645 さんが質問に書かれていたチュートリアルから GitHub のリポジトリへ行き、サブディレクトリにある `CMakeLists.txt` を調べていました。

Comment: 検索ワード感謝します。丁寧にありがとうございました。